# Ajax call, response processing issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have this simple form which posts content with an Ajax call.

```
<form id="NewDataForm">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" required />
    <button id="saveNewData" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <div id="errorNewData" class="alert alert-danger text-center" role="alert"></div>
</form>
```

Jquery code:

```
$('#saveNewData').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#errorNewData').hide();
    if ($('#NewDataForm')[0].checkValidity()) {
        $.ajax({
           url: '/admin/includes/post.php',
           type: 'POST',
           data: $('form#NewDataForm').serialize()
        })
        .done(function(msg) {
           alert(msg);
           if (msg === 'go') {
              // some actions
           }else{
              $('#errorNewData').show();
              $('#errorNewData').html(msg);
           }
        });
    } else {
        $('#NewDataForm')[0].reportValidity();
    }
});
```

Currently, post.php just contains this for testing purpose:

```
<?php
echo 'go';
?>
```

But whatever the content returned by post.php, it always shows #errorNewData content.

**if (msg === 'go')** is never true, even if the answer is go.

However alert(msg) shows 'go', and #errorNewData also show 'go'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`msg` is likely `"go\n"` or `"go\r\n"` not exactly `"go"`, because there's probably a newline after the closing `?>` tag. (Note: [PHP guidance](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) is to leave that off.) So this check should work:

```
if (msg.trim() === "go")
```

...or if you remove the `?>` tag, your previous check may start working.

This is one of the reasons I almost always make my replies to ajax calls JSON; leading and trailing whitespace have no impact on it. I'd probably have:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode(Array("success" => True));
```

and then in the JavaScript:

```
if (msg.success) {
```

(jQuery will see the content type and automatically parse the JSON for you.)